# Differnce between color image and false color image

Tags: visible-light, image-processing

I am currently trying to understand the difference between true colour and false colour.

So true colour to me is what we perceive as a person, i.e I take a photo and the photo is a true colour image as it the same colour as what I would see in real life, and each pixel would then have a value of RGB to form the different shades that are being seen of that colour.

Where false colour is where one value is assigned per pixel I.e one pixel can only be red, another blue ect, so then for example vegation is normally show in red of varying intensity which show where the most vegation.

Is this along the correct lines?

sorry for wrong tags as I am not sure what this type of question would come under.

Comment: It would forget about the pixels stuff. In terms of photography, false color is the artificial coloring of a picture because it was took with a camera that was not sensing visible light. For example heat cameras, what is the color of heat? To show you this contrast visually you must relate the range of temperatures with a scale of color, e.g. red for hot and black for cold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False color photos are ones in which the colors exhibited in the true image have been either exaggerated to make some aspect of the image easier to perceive, or substituted with an entirely different palette of colors for the same purpose.

False color is also added to black and white images where no color information existed in them in the first place- to make them look more visually interesting.

These uses of false color are in addition to the one you cited, namely the assignment of a color in an image to represent a wavelength of light that the human eye cannot perceive.